# How to group condition into "Other" category

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a data frame expressed in a bar chart (picture below)
I want to group some Target formation with (Numbers < 5) to a group called (Other). How could I do that?

Barchart:

[image]

data:

```
            Numbers
Target A    34
Target B    22
Target C    13
Target P    13
Target D    7
Target E    6
Target F    4
Target G    2
Target H    2
Target I    1
Target J    1
Target K    1
Target L    1
Target M    1
Target N    1
Target O    1
```

Comment: please post your dataframe as text not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the index into a `Target formation` column. Then for rows where `Numbers < 5`, change their `Target formation` to "Other":

```py
df = df.rename_axis('Target formation').reset_index()
df.loc[df.Numbers < 5, 'Target formation'] = 'Other'

#    Target formation  Numbers
# 0          Target A       34
# 1          Target B       22
# 2          Target C       13
# 3          Target P       13
# 4          Target D        7
# 5          Target E        6
# 6             Other        4
# 7             Other        2
# 8             Other        2
# 9             Other        1
# 10            Other        1
# 11            Other        1
# 12            Other        1
# 13            Other        1
# 14            Other        1
# 15            Other        1
```

Then use [**`groupby.sum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) which will aggregate "Other" as one entry:

```py
(df.groupby('Target formation').Numbers
   .sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
   .plot.barh())
```

[image: grouped bar plot with aggregated "other"]

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you may need to reset the index, just replace `Labels` with your column name.

```
# values under threshold
other = df.loc[df['Numbers'] < 5]['Numbers'].sum()

new_row = {'Labels': 'Other', 'values': other}
df[df['Numbers'] >= 5].append(new_row, -1)
```